# IF condition in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could you please correct me?

I am writing this logic in my stored procedure but I get an error:

```
DECLARE @PERIOD AS VARCHAR(7)

BEGIN
    IF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3)
    BEGIN
        SET @PERIOD = YEAR(GETDATE() + ' Q1'
    END
    ELSE IF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6)
    BEGIN
        SET @PERIOD = YEAR(GETDATE() + ' Q2'
    END
    ELSE IF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9)
    BEGIN
        SET @PERIOD = YEAR(GETDATE() + ' Q3'
    END
    ELSE IF (MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 or MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12)
    BEGIN
        SET @PERIOD = YEAR(GETDATE() + ' Q4'
    END
END
```

Error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Comment: You are in SQL no need for the == try replacing with =

Comment: Thank you Dan for pointing out for me.. My god I am not sure why I did not recognized that :) now I am getting new error. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is hard to read, and unfortunately riddled with syntax issues.

You're missing several parenthesis in the `SET` statements, and you can't concatenate an `int` and a `varchar`.

Try this...

```
DECLARE @PERIOD AS VARCHAR(7)

DECLARE @MONTHVAL INT, @YEARVAL VARCHAR(4)
SET @MONTHVAL = MONTH(GETDATE())
SET @YEARVAL = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()))

SET @PERIOD = CASE WHEN @MONTHVAL IN (1,2,3) THEN @YEARVAL + ' Q1'
                   WHEN @MONTHVAL IN (4,5,6) THEN @YEARVAL + ' Q2'
                   WHEN @MONTHVAL IN (7,8,9) THEN @YEARVAL + ' Q3'
                   WHEN @MONTHVAL IN (10,11,12) THEN @YEARVAL + ' Q4'
              END

SELECT @PERIOD
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I think this is what you're looking for.

```
declare @PERIOD AS VARCHAR(7)

IF( DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 1 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 2 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 3)


    BEGIN
       SET @PERIOD = CAST (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ' Q1'
    END
else IF( DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 4 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 5 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())= 6)
    BEGIN
       SET @PERIOD =  CAST (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ' Q2'
    END
else IF( DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 7 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 8 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 9)
    BEGIN
       SET @PERIOD =  CAST (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ' Q3'
    END
else IF ( DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 10 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 11 or  DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 12)
    BEGIN
       SET  @PERIOD = CAST (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)+ ' Q4'
    END
```

Sorry for the slack answer, limited time. I may flesh it out later but I hope this gets you up and running.